# How to make IntelliJ understand annotations

Tags: ide, annotations, intellij-idea

I have recently switched from using Eclipse to IntelliJ, and am preferring the experience.

However, the IDE is not understanding any of the Annotations.  I am using Spring @Autowired annotation as well as some of the Spring-WS annotations and the IDE is telling me that they are unresolved.

When the project is built using Maven, it builds fine, and the Annotations are recognised in Eclipse.

Im sure this is a simple setup thing, but cannot find any information on how to set it up.

Comment: Have you properly imported your Maven project into IntelliJ? Then it should see the dependencies correctly.

Comment: If I check the dependencies then I can see the spring-ws library there, but there are no annotations package.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Resolved. The IDE was not parsing the properties in the POM.  When I changed the dependencies <version>${spring.ws.version}</version> to <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version> it worked.  New problem for me to solve now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter said, when correctly importing the Maven project the dependencies should be correctly recognized. The IntelliJ manual has a [section on how to import a Maven project](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-maven-project.html).

Answer (score 1):

For the record, in our project pom, we have the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The former two have been present already before implementing a web service, so they may not be required strictly for web services.